# Unable to send sign up data from front-end to backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to send form data through HTTP request from AngularJs to Nodejs.
I have included header files for allowing cross origin requests in angular still its not working.

The error I am getting is:

> Failed to load localhost:4000/Register: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.

Code for my http request:

```
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "localhost:4000/Register",
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
                },
                contentType: "application/json;",
                data: myJSON
            });
            request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = data;
                console.log($scope.message);
            });
            request.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert( "failure message: " +  data);
            });
```

This is my server code on nodejs :

```
const db = knex ({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1',
        user : 'postgres',
        //Enter the password which you entered during postgres installation
        password : '',
        //Whatever the database name be, replace it with 'spdb'
        database : 'spdb'
    }
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(database.users);
})
app.post('/Register', (req,res)=>{
    const {fname, lname, rollno, section, password, email, role } = req.body;
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
db.transaction(trx => {
    trx.insert({
    hash: hash,
    email: email,
    rollno: rollno
})
    .into('login')
    .returning('email')
    .then(loginEmail => {
    return trx('users')
        .returning('*')
        .insert({
            fname: fname,
        lname: lname,
        rollno: rollno,
        section: section,
        email: loginEmail[0],
        joined: new Date(),
        role: role
        })
        .then(user => {
        res.json(user[0]);
})
})
.then(trx.commit)
    .then(trx.rollback)
})
.catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))

})
app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log('app is running on port 4000');
})
```

Comment: Its a CORS issues. Try google plugin or fix from server side , or add proper header

Comment: 1. There is no such argument as contentType. It must be in headers object, as
"Content-Type": "application/json".
Check the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: @ShashankVivek  enabled this google plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en  still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the base route '/' return the webpage, try having the url of the request just be:

```
var request = $http({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/register',
  ...
});
```

Comment: My server is running on port 4000  so if I use url:'/Register' it is going to localhost:8000/Register . The error I am getting is:**POST http://localhost:8000/Register 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Comment: Is your server running on port 4000 or 8000? if the web page is being return by going to localhost:4000/ then in the js by using '/register' should call the host

Comment: My server is running on port 4000 and front end on port 8000

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't work then. If you could have them running  on the same port, then you wouldn't have to worry about cors issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add CORS extension from chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can run both (front-end and back-end) on same port in developmen

Answer (score 0):

The cross origin headers should be sent by the server, give a look and integrate https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors in your Node JS app and you would be good to go :)

Hope this helps,
Cheers.